# Is it possible to get battery status and then play a sound while app is in the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Would it be possible to get a `UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification` while an app is running in the background? And then use `AVAudioPlayer` to play a sound right after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification won't wake your app up; there is a [selected list of allowable background modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) for which your app can handle notifications. But keep in mind that, while playing audio like that in the background *may be possible* code wise, Apple will reject your app for doing that. So if you're hoping to get approved in the App Store, you should avoid.